# PHP arrays merge in one multidimensional if year exists in both arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays (brochures and brochures_so). In both arrays i have multiple years.

**Brochures array:**

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [2022]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(4) "test"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2021]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(8) "Wiskunde"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [2021]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(43) "Informatieverwerving en -verwerking met ICT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Brochures_so array**

```
array(22) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [2022]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure_so"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(8) "Wiskunde"
        ["onderwijsniveau"]=>
        string(25) "1ste graad a- en b-stroom"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [2022]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure_so"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(10) "Nederlands"
        ["onderwijsniveau"]=>
        string(25) "1ste graad a- en b-stroom"
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [2021]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure_so"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(3) "PAV"
        ["onderwijsniveau"]=>
        string(13) "3de graad bso"
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [2021]=>
    array(1) {
      ["brochure_so"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["vakgebied"]=>
        string(35) "Kritisch denken & mediawijsheid"
        ["onderwijsniveau"]=>
        string(9) "3e graad "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I try to build an array like this.

```
/* This multidimensional array works */

$peilingen = [
    [2022 => ["brochure_so" => ["vakgebied" => "Wiskunde", "onderwijsniveau" => "1ste graad a- en b-stroom"], "brochure" => ["vakgebied" => ""]]],
    [2022 => ["brochure_so" => ["vakgebied" => "Nederlands", "onderwijsniveau" => "1ste graad a- en b-stroom"], "brochure" => ["vakgebied" => ""]]],
    [2021 => ["brochure_so" => ["vakgebied" => "PAV", "onderwijsniveau" => "3de graad bso"], "brochure" => ["vakgebied" => "Wiskunde"]]],
    [2021 => ["brochure_so" => ["vakgebied" => "Kritisch denken & mediawijsheid", "onderwijsniveau" => "3de graad bso"], "brochure" => ["vakgebied" => "Informatieverwerving en -verwerking met ICT"]]],
];

echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Jaar</th><th>Brochure</th><th>Brochure_so</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach ($peilingen as $peiling) {
    foreach ($peiling as $jaar => $peil) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $jaar . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $peil["brochure"]["vakgebied"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $peil["brochure_so"]["vakgebied"] . " | " . $peil["brochure_so"]["onderwijsniveau"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

How i can merge brochures array and brochures_so array and come out like this multidimensional $peilingen (like above)?

Example:
In brochures array you have one item key 2022 and in brochures_so you have two items with key 2022.
Merge array if key years matches in both arrays.

The main goal is to output this html table:

| Jaar | Brochure_so | Brochure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Wiskunde - 1ste graad a- en b-stroom | Test |
| 2022 | Nederlands - 1ste graad a- en b-stroom |  |
| 2021 | PAV - 3de graad bso | Wiskunde |
| 2021 | Kritisch denken & mediawijsheid - 3de graad bso |  |

Comment: Ok, so what is the question?

Comment: Hi, well i try to merge the array brochures and brochures_so like the multidimensional array $peilingen that i now build manually.